# How to display multiple (unknown number of slideshows) on one page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, carousel, slideshow

So here is a codepen link. https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/KKvqjYm
The thing is: I have multiple cards (unknown number, it depends on the number of users who post) and for every card, I want to display the text through a slideshow. This codepen link worked great in the first day, but now it's just not recognizing the slideshows anymore and doesn't display any text. My page looks something like this:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <?php  for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) { ?>
         <div class="mySlides"> Display different text here.. </div>
      <?php } ?>
         <a class="prev">❮</a>
         <a class="next">❯</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dot-container">
      <?php for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) { ?>  <!-- where $len is another unknown variable (like.. 
                                                                  not something fixed) -->
        <span class="dot"></span> 
   <?php } ?>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to calculate and assign value dynamically to $len variable:

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <style>
                * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .slideshow {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        
        /* Slideshow container */
        .slideshow-container {
            /*  position: fixed;
            margin: auto; */
            position: relative;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #f1f1f1f1;
        }
        
        /* Slides */
        .mySlides {
            display: none;
            padding: 80px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-bottom: 0;
        }
        
        /* Next & previous buttons */
        .prev,
        .next {
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            width: auto;
            margin-top: -30px;
            padding: 16px;
            color: #888;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
            user-select: none;
        }
        
        /* Position the "next button" to the right */
        .next {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        }
        
        /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
        .prev:hover,
        .next:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            color: white;
        }
        
        /* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
        .dot-container {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
            background: #ddd;
            /*  position: fixed;
            margin-top: 200px; */
            width: 400px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        
        /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
        .dot {
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            margin: 0 2px;
            background-color: #bbb;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
        }
        
        /* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
        .active,
        .dot:hover {
            background-color: #717171;
        }
        
        /* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
        q {
            font-style: italic;
        }
        
        /* Add a blue color to the author */
        .author {
            color: cornflowerblue;
        }
        </style>
            <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <body>  
            
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="slideshow-container">
              <?php  

    $len=6;
//put your query logic here to get counter and assign to $len
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) { ?>
                 <div class="mySlides"> Display different text here..<?php echo $i; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
                 <a class="prev">❮</a>
                 <a class="next">❯</a>
            </div>
        
            <div class="dot-container">
              <?php for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) { ?>  <!-- where $len is another unknown variable (like.. 
                                                                          not something fixed) -->
                <span class="dot"></span> 
           <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
         
        <script>
            const slideshows = document.querySelectorAll(".slideshow");
        
        slideshows.forEach((slideshow) => {
            var dots = slideshow.querySelectorAll(".dot");
            var prev = slideshow.querySelector(".prev");
            var next = slideshow.querySelector(".next");
        
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showSlides(slideIndex);
        
            prev.addEventListener("click", () => showSlides((slideIndex -= 1)));
            next.addEventListener("click", () => showSlides((slideIndex += 1)));
        
            dots.forEach((dot, i) => {
                dot.addEventListener("click", () => showSlides((slideIndex = i + 1)));
            });
        
            function showSlides(n) {
                var i;
                var slides = slideshow.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        
                if (n > slides.length) {
                    slideIndex = 1;
                }
                if (n < 1) {
                    slideIndex = slides.length;
                }
                for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                    slides[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
            }
        });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: oh. nono, I know the value at the running time. It just depends on the number of posts that I have

Comment: @deniz_info Please check with above code , is it working?

Comment: yes, it's working, but what if I don't know the value when I am outside the card container?

Comment: I mean, I have a database with user posts, so I will not know the number of posts until I make the connection to the database and select all the posts from there

Comment: you need to make query before html tag to get cointer of all post and you can use that counter for slide. @deniz_info

Comment: Its not necessary to put outside card container, you need to put before for loop. @deniz_info

Comment: well.. is outside the loop, but still not working :((

Comment: @deniz_info I have updated code. Please check.

Comment: here is the problem. any other value of len which is not right after the <body> tag is not working, even though if I echo it, it shows the right value. It doesn't matter where I put it, it will not work. Is this a php problem or what? I don't get it anymore